# Why is it not taking my user input string: name?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class My_Lab02
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
   int a, b, c;
   String name, greeting;

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   // 1st Part
   System.out.println("Please enter two integers: ");
   a = input.nextInt();
   b = input.nextInt();
   System.out.println("***  \"" + a + "/" + b + "=" + a/b + "\"");

   // 2nd Part
   System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
   name = input.nextLine();
   greeting = "Hello, ";
   System.out.println(greeting + name);   
   }
}
```

As soon as I run the program The first part of the code with the int a,b works fine,  but as soon as I get to to the second part of the code it just prints out Hello, and  the program ends, BUT! If I comment out the first part of the code, the second part of the code works how It should and allows you to enter both first and last name, in one string. Then prints out "Hello, Joe Bob"

I don't understand how the first part of the code is effecting the second part of my code.

This is a sample run of how the program runs incorrectly:

```
Please enter two integers: 
30
4
***  "30/4=7"
Enter your name: 
Hello,
```

This is how the finial code needs to be:

```
Example run 2:
Enter two integers: 15 4
*** “15/ 4 = 3”
Enter your name: Tom Cruise
Hello, Tom Cruise.
The first letter in your name is T!
Your name contains 10 characters.
HELLO, TOM CRUISE
```

But I need to work out this first bug, before I can finish the assignment.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: your code does not have any line that counts characters of your name?

Comment: "But I need to work out this first bug, before I can finish the assignment."

Comment: OK sounds good cuz you are aware of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b = input.nextInt();` doesn't consume the next newline. So when you call

```
input.nextLine()
```

you get a single newline. You could just read it.

```
input.nextLine(); // <-- by adding this
System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
name = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: his code does not have any line to counts characters of entered name?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! is there a different why that I could get the b variable with out having to put that "Filler" in there?

Comment: @KickButtowski OP didn't ask for the final output (and if OP had, that would have been met with a won't do your homework). Instead OP asked a very specific question with a very specific answer.

Comment: @MasonYounger Per the [`nextLine()` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), *Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.* However [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28int%29) *Scans the next token of the input as an `int`*.